# I am trying to login into the bitbucket through VSCode extension( Jira and Bitbucket(Atlassian Labs)). I am getting below error in my browser :

Tags: visual-studio-code, bitbucket

*Something went wrong
"Error authenticating with bbcloud: Error: Error fetching Bitbucket
tokens: Error[ERR_SOCKET_CLOSED]: Socket is closed
Give it a moment and try again"*

Comment: please add bitbucket extension version and vscode version

Comment: any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting VScode as administrator and try again

Comment: Why? Running applications with elevated privileges should be avoided unless there's a very good reason.